# Induced topologies by Metric Spaces continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $T$ the corresponding topology on $X$.  Fix $a$ as an element in X.  Prove that the map $f: (X,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = d(a,x)$ is continuous.

I know I need to show that the inverse image of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is an open set in $X$.

I know that an open set in $X$ is a subset of $X$ whose distance from $a$ is r because of the definition of an open ball in $X$.  The inverse image of an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ (call it $O$) is the set of all points in $X$ whose distance from a is an $r$ that's an element of the open set $O$ in $r$.

I feel like this thinking is right, but I don't know how to prove this further.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you want to prove that $f^{-1}(O)$ is open. What is it precisely that you need to show?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can show it is uniformly continuous. Note that $$|d(a,x)-d(a,y)|\le d(x,y)$$

for every $x,y\in X$.